# Vuetify3 how to stop moving button

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm new to vuetify and I'm struggling to solve a problem, but I don't know how to google it.

Here is a problem;
v-textarea is used along with :hint, and if there is no input, the hint message is displayed below textarea. When a user tries to click button, the button moves a little because this hint message disappears. I would like to know how to make v-textarea and the hint message together not affecting the placements of other components.

```js
  <div>
    <v-container fluid="false">
      <v-row>
        <v-textarea
          v-model="searchesText"
          :label="label"
          :hint="hint"
          :rows="5"
          hide-details="auto"
        />
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </div>

  <v-container>
    <div>
      <v-row>
        <v-spacer />
        <v-btn fab color="green" :disabled="!searchable" @click="onClickSearch">
          Click
          <!-- <v-icon :icon="mdiMagnify"></v-icon> -->
        </v-btn>
      </v-row>
    </div>
  </v-container>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `hide-details="auto"` to `:hide-details="false"` or remove the property altogether. That should work for you.

[working example on codepen](https://codepen.io/milidubey/pen/yLEXyXg)

Vuetify uses that space to render validation errors or hints. In your case since it's set to auto, Vuetify gets rid of the space when no hint is applicable (i.e until user hasn't focused on the textarea) and then adds the space back when text area is focused. This is causing a slight layout shift.

As you have just started out with Vuetify, it would be good to learn more about containers, rows, and columns to better structure your code.

Ideally a container can contain multiple rows. A **row should always be followed by a column** tag and you can add elements (e.g textarea, buttons, cards, divs etc) inside columns. That would ensure uniform spacing between elements as well.

You can refer to the Codepen link above for both these issues.

Cheers!